# Arm Board Bring Up

Tags: hardware, arm

Can anybody tell me where I can find information related to How to Bringup any arm board? I am looking for an overview as I am novice in ARM related stuffs. Any link/document will do ...It will be gr8 help if i can look for a case-study

any arm based board can be considered..I am looking for just a case study...simple in few steps??

Comment: What do you mean "bring up"? Also, have you read the data sheets for your components?

Comment: which arm?  There different kinds with different architectures, which may result in different procedures for initialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every single ARM "board" will be different. Read the datasheet for the ARM chip you have, that should have a section near the start about booting. Also, read the datasheet about your board, as it made have flash/boot loaders on there. If there are no loaders on the board, you'll have to either set the jumpers for the ARM (if that type supoprts it) to read from external rom, or JTAG the initial boot code into it.

Basically: Read the datasheets. Programming a device like an ARM isn't your usual compile/run stratergy like most software, especially not in the first stage.

edit:
If you don't even have a board yet, try going for this one:
http://beagleboard.org/

It has and ARM on it (as well as a decent GPU).

Comment: Nice!  I always thought $150 was a bit much to spend for a dev kit for doing homebrew / hobbiest activities...

Answer (score 2):

Check the [DLP-2232PB-G](http://www.ftdichip.com/Documents/DataSheets/DLP/dlp-2232pbv15.pdf) [evaluation kit from FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/EvaluationKits/DIPModules.htm).  Looks great for newbies trying to get into microcontrollers, and it comes with everything you need.  It's a PIC controller - not an ARM controller, but the easiest starting point that I've seen... and same basic methods of development.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with any documentation the IC manufacturer may have on "getting started".

Answer (score 1):

http://free-electrons.com/doc/porting-kernel.odp

This link gives a good overview of the bringup of the board with a CPU for which the linux support package is available.

Linux sources in arch/arm have mach-* which are cpus supported by Linux Kernel.

With in the mach-* dir, there are some board specific files that are board specific BSPs.

You can take the process elucidated in this article and try using in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ok6410-h at http://www.arm9board.net/sel/prddetail.aspx?id=348&pid=200

Quit a nice kicking-start kit coming with everyting you would ever need: documentations, source code, example programs.

recommendable for both newbies and experienced.