# Running bare kernel on android device

Tags: android, kernel

Is it possible that we can run a bare kernel on some android device with minimum of adb support to connect to the device? Or Is there any such ROM available which has this capability?

Regards

Shahzad

Comment: Maybe something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503465/arm-board-bring-up but ROM without GUI is not useful for a lot of people

Comment: @zapl Yes. Its not useful for all but from the research perspective, it could be useful for someone like bench marking the device without any other workload except the target application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, no it is not possible, with the assumption that the "bare kernel" would not have the necesary drivers for "some android device".  I suppose some version of the kernel (assuming you mean the AOSP kernel) might work on a particular device, but not in general on all devices.

Comment: What if we consider Samsung galaxy s2 in particular. I am not an expert of Android but curious to know as in Desktop PC, we can have a bare kernel and its up to the user to install Windows manager and which one to install. Is there any kind of such thing in the world of android?

Comment: By kernel, do you mean the Linux kernel or the Android kernel? By Android kernel, I mean what is released through the AOSP. In either case, to run either without modification, the kernel would require drivers for all hardware used.  Do you want to run Linux or Android on this device?  According to Wikipedia, the Galaxy S2 has three versions, each with a different SoC (more or less the processor).  This complicates the issue.

Comment: Yes. Definitely it will be an android kernel with all the drivers for the device. But my main concern here is running the kernel only without the platform.